# List files from a large directory on AIX machine

Tags: java, shell, perl, unix, aix

I have a directory that contains around 3 million files.  Once a day I need to run a process that creates a separate file containing file names from that large directory that have `.html` extension.  Typically, of the 3 million files that are there, 500,000 will have that `.html` extension.  I am using the following:

```
find dirname -name "*.html"
```

However, this runs for about 3 hours before it completes.  Is there a faster way to do this?

Update: I did some testing with Perl and Java.  Using Perl to get the contents of this directory and create a file of `.html` I tried the following (note the times):

```
my @files = </$dirname/*.html>  # 45 minutes
```

When I tried this with Java using:

```
    final File[] files = dirname.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.endsWith(".html");
                }
            });
```

How is Java able to do this in 3 minutes as opposed to Perl or any Unix command I can think of?

Comment: The files contained in this directory are pretty small.  Averaging 400k per file.

Comment: `ls` and `find` will hit buffer limit because of the number of files and need to do many calls.  You can write your own version of `ls` with a larger buffer.

Comment: How would i write my own ls?

Comment: look like you wrote one in Java already!

Comment: You should quote more code. For example `find directory -name '*.html' -exec echo {} \; >>listfile` is slower than `find directory -name '*.html' >listfile`

Answer (score 2):

The default file glob() sorts the file list; that's why it's taking a long time.

```
my @files = </$dirname/*.html>  # 45 minutes
```

Try reading the directory directly:

```
my @files = ();
opendir my $dh, $dirname or die "could not open $dirname: $!\n";
while( my $file = readdir $dh ){
    push @files, $file if $file =~ /\.html$/;
}
closedir $dh or die "could not close $dirname: $!\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use "getdents" in place of ls/find

ls and practically every other method of listing a directory (including python os.listdir, find .) rely on libc readdir(). However readdir() only reads 32K of directory entries at a time, which means that if you have a lot of files in the same directory (i.e. 500M of directory entries) it is going to take an insanely long time to read all the directory entries, especially on a slow disk. For directories containing a large number of files, you'll need to dig deeper than tools that rely on readdir(). You will need to use the getdents() syscall directly, rather than helper methods from libc.

You can find the C code to list the files using getdents() from [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html):

There are two modifications you will need to do in order quickly list all the files in a directory.

First, increase the buffer size from X to something like 5 megabytes.

```
#define BUF_SIZE 1024*1024*5
```

Then modify the main loop where it prints out the information about each file in the directory to skip entries with inode == 0. I did this by adding

```
if (dp->d_ino != 0) printf(...);
```

In my case I also really only cared about the file names in the directory so I also rewrote the printf() statement to only print the filename.

```
if(d->d_ino) printf("%sn ", (char *) d->d_name);
```

Compile it (it doesn't need any external libraries, so it's super simple to do)

```
gcc listdir.c -o listdir
```

Now just run

```
./listdir [directory with insane number of files]
```

Comment: Thanks nakulbansal!  However the link you provided to getdents is not available.

Comment: @PeteY Huh? The link works perfect for me. It's a manpage with the `listdir.c` code as an example. Btw, it's the same output I get when I issue `man getdents` on my command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ls like below

```
\ls -U
```

-U     do not sort; list entries in directory order